# Using a python script in google chrome extension

Tags: python, web, google-chrome-extension

I have written a python script using NLTK to get sentiment of text. I am trying to build a Google Chrome extension that gets the selected text and displays the sentiment of the text.

I did see Native Messaging but it doesn't seem to work, they have used an app as the sample.

Is there a way where I can get the selected text from the extension and then send it to my python script and then make the extension display the sentiment of the text?

I did watch ajax tutorials too but to no avail.

Comment: a quick google shows me that this will require some sort of client install on the part of the user(perhaps further searching will yield different results) and in that case you might as well turn the python script into a server and just send data to it from the extension to side step the issue all together

Comment: I am trying it out by creating django app and sending ajax request to my localhost but I am getting an error-CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: you can read more on [CORES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) but the important bit is that you are missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. if you are only testing on a local network you can use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow all origins, but avoid deploying that

Comment: Yes. Thank you a lot! I did try it out and it seems to work. But I am not able to get an alternative to not deploying that!

Comment: i think once you have an actual domain, you  will use that

Comment: I keep getting a Not Found: /sentiment/ "GET /sentiment/?number=219 HTTP/1.1" 404 1714 error whenever I call the url with ajax even though I do have that url in my django app. (I'm so sorry I am an absolute beginner)

Comment: i have no experience with django. are you running it all on one machine? are you trying to access the web service by name? ip? which ip? django might need to be told to listen on specific interfaces

Comment: well yes. it was a 404 error that was being raised because of an if condition. i figured it out. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, could you share how you implemented a django server for your chrome extension ?

Comment: @TonyStark I used the localhost